# From Patch-based Classifier to Full Image classifier

Tags: cnn, image-classification, transfer-learning

I was wondering if it is feasible to train patch-based image classifier, due to small amount of data, and then use it in order to initialize training for full image classification, but this time on different set of classes?

Specifically, I am having trouble understanding how a network trained on 227x227 image patches can be used to initialize training a network for lets say 2000x2000 images. Is there anyone who can help me ether understand this problem or point me to the right direction? Thanks!